# Python Web Crawler for JavaScript Generated URLs

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I am trying to use some Python web crawler to download about 3000 PDFs from a website. However, the URLs of those PDFs are generated by JavaScript function. So, I am wondering if there is any tutorial on how to achieve this?

For example, the URL linked to `Alberto European Hairspray (Aerosol) - All Variants` will be generated after clicking `onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$placeBody$gridView$gridView&#39;,&#39;DocumentCenter.aspx?did={0}$0&#39`.
So the question is how to let the web crawler to get the computed URL.

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="image" src="App_Graphics/PDFDocument.gif" alt="MSDS" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$placeBody$gridView$gridView&#39;,&#39;DocumentCenter.aspx?did={0}$0&#39;);return false;" />
        </td>
        <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$placeBody$gridView$gridView&#39;,&#39;MSDSDetail.aspx?did={0}$0&#39;)">Alberto European Hairspray (Aerosol) - All Variants</a>
        </td>
        <td>Unilever PLC</td>
        <td>8131-01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-alternate">
        <td>
            <input type="image" src="App_Graphics/PDFDocument.gif" alt="MSDS" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$placeBody$gridView$gridView&#39;,&#39;DocumentCenter.aspx?did={0}$1&#39;);return false;" />
        </td>
        <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$placeBody$gridView$gridView&#39;,&#39;MSDSDetail.aspx?did={0}$1&#39;)">Alberto European Mousse (Aerosol) - All Variants</a>
        </td>
        <td>Unilever PLC</td>
        <td>8132-01</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Use a JavaScript interpreter ([SpiderMonkey](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-spidermonkey), for example) to execute the code and then go ahead with HTML parsing. Using Qt's WebKit is a good approach also, but probably slower.

Comment: @tao.hong You're welcome. I had the same problem and I know it's somewhat disappointing :P

Answer (score 1):

Another option is that you might use Selenium to [execute js](https://www.google.lv/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=selenium%20execute%20javascript&oq=selenuim%20executer%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5923j0j7) and get computed urls.